# Unity How to increase the speed of a framerate dependent function?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, math, time

I am developing a 2D game in Unity, and I want to use the Atan function to move the camera so that it moves faster if the closer it is to the player. I wanted to make it framerate independent by doing this:

```
float deltax = (Player.position.x - transform.position.x);
float deltay = (Player.position.y + 2.5f - transform.position.y);

Vector2 previousframe = new Vector2(PrimArcTan(deltax), PrimArcTan(deltay));
Vector2 currentFrame = new Vector2
(PrimArcTan(deltax + ArcTan(deltax) * CameraSpeed * Time.deltaTime),
 PrimArcTan(deltay + ArcTan(deltay) * CameraSpeed *  Time.deltaTime));

delta.x = (currentFrame.x - previousframe.x) * ((deltax > 0) ? 1 : -1);
delta.y = (currentFrame.y - previousframe.y) * ((deltay > 0) ? 1 : -1);
Move(delta);
```

This works for lower CameraSpeeds, however if I increase the speed it starts shaking violently at lower framerates.

I tried to put the cameraspeed at different places, but all of them had the same effect. I also tried to change te ATan function to like 8 * Atan(x). But that also made It shake. I cant seem to figure it out...

Comment: Sounds like a question for over on [the gamedev site](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/) instead.

Comment: Hi, is it shaking in the x or y direction, or both? Is there anything to stop the camera 'overshooting' as you increase camera speed? I'm guessing this is what's happening, causing it to 'hunt' around the target position. I'd start by plotting all the variable values and trying to trace the cause back from there, or even better try and construct a stand alone test harness for the problem.

Comment: To avoid overshooting you should probably rather use [`MoveTowards`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Mathf.MoveTowards.html)

Answer (score 0):

I can not test it so it is a bit of a long shot but it seems like the camera is overshooting the player position.

```
float deltax = (Player.position.x - transform.position.x);
float deltay = (Player.position.y + 2.5f - transform.position.y);

Vector2 previousframe = new Vector2(PrimArcTan(deltax), PrimArcTan(deltay));
Vector2 currentFrame = new Vector2
(PrimArcTan(deltax + ArcTan(deltax) * CameraSpeed * Time.deltaTime),
 PrimArcTan(deltay + ArcTan(deltay) * CameraSpeed *  Time.deltaTime));

delta.x = (currentFrame.x - previousframe.x) * Mathf.Sign(deltax);
delta.y = (currentFrame.y - previousframe.y) * Mathf.Sign(deltay);

if (Mathf.Abs(delta.x) > Mathf.Abs(deltax)) { delta.x = deltax; }
if (Mathf.Abs(delta.y) > Mathf.Abs(deltay)) { delta.y = deltay; }

Move(delta);
```

This should clamp the movement to not go past than the target position.